# Render beveled border on SVG rect

Tags: svg, svg-filters

Is it possible to render a border of a SVG rect to emulate an outset?

- with CSS?
- with filters?

NB: It has to be a single scalable simple rect object, so I don't want to build it with paths / composite objects.

[image]

Comment: You will need to draw the border as 2 different paths with 2 different fills

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with a filter. You do it by drawing a masking shape in the SVG and doing the stroking in the filter.

```html
<svg width="600px" height="800px" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <filter id="rect-and-stroke" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feFlood flood-color="red" result="red-stroke"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="orange" result="orange-stroke"/>
    <feFlood x="10" y="10" width="180" height="80" flood-color="yellow" result="yellow-field"/>
     
     <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="red-stroke" result="red-partial"/> 
     <feComposite operator="out" in2="SourceGraphic" in="orange-stroke" result="orange-partial"/> 
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="red-partial" />
      <feMergeNode in="orange-partial" />
       <feMergeNode in="yellow-field" />    
      
    </feMerge>
    
  </filter>
  
  
  <path filter="url(#rect-and-stroke)" fill="black" d="M 0 0  L 10 10 180 80 200 100 0 100Z"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Great, elegant. But it doesn't seem to work with a simple rect. I'd also like it to be scalable so I don't have to specify coordinates in the filters.

Comment: You draw the rect within the filter by using floods and composites based on the width/height established by the path in the main SVG. If you want it to be scalable, you can do that within the filter by using objectBoundingBox units - but please specify your requirements more completely and I'd be happy to add an example.

Comment: ** It has to be a single scalable simple rect object, so I don't want to build it with paths / composite objects **

Comment: You can't do that with SVG at the moment. Sorry :(